# MySQL not using ports in xampp?

Tags: mysql, xampp, ports

I installed Joomla and updated it to the latest version, but MySQL crashed, and when I start it back up it doesn't use any ports??
[image]
I've tried restarting xampp and it doesn't fix it. After a while of MySQL being opened, it crashes and windows gives me the error:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: mysqld.exe
  Application Version:  10.1.21.0
  Application Timestamp:    587e81ec
  Fault Module Name:    mysqld.exe
  Fault Module Version: 10.1.21.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   587e81ec
  Exception Code:   80000003
  Exception Offset: 00463db0
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

If i try going to PHPMyAdmin, it shows this : [image]

Can I please get some help?

Answer (score 0):

You might have some luck backing up your htdocs folder and re-installing xampp from scratch.

Comment: This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to change the `port no==> mysqli.default_port = 3306` in `php.ini` file and restart the system..Hope it will fix

Comment: i don't see this in there..? What line is it?

Comment: have u seen `php.ini` file ? It must be in your directory..else create `php.ini` file and add to your root folder directory..

Comment: I see php.ini in /php/